# Installing Domain SSL is not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, domain, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I have a Linode Server running Debian 7.5 & Apache2

I have the following files stored in the `/etc/ssl/localcerts/` directory:

- www.test-site.com.key
- www.test-site.com.csr
- www.test-site.com.crt
- intermediate.crt

I have the following configuration in my `test-site.com.conf` file in the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.test-site.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.test-site.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/intermediate.crt
  #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/ca.pem

# Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@test-site.com
  ServerName  www.test-site.com
  # ServerAlias test-site.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public/test-site.com/public/
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/user/public/test-site.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/user/public/test-site.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone identify what i'm doing wrong? All the files are set-up correctly, I think. But still the SSL installation seems to have not worked.

UPDATE

Here is an image describing the connection:

[image: connection description]

Here is the contents of `ports.conf` in the directory `/etc/apache2/` :

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.

    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: first of all, ssl is on 443, not port 80

Comment: *the SSL installation seems to have not worked.* Please explain in detail. [ask]

Comment: Your browser is seeing a **selfsigned** cert; is that what you intend? If so, you shouldn't expect browsers to trust it, and it makes no sense to have an "intermediate" file because a selfsigned cert doesn't *have* a chain. If you intended to use a CA-issued cert, you apparently didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure the SSL mod is enabled

```
a2enmod ssl
```

then you need to change your config to something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.test-site.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/www.test-site.com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/intermediate.crt
 #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/ca.pem

# Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
ServerAdmin admin@test-site.com
ServerName  www.test-site.com
# ServerAlias test-site.com

# Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /home/user/public/test-site.com/public/
# Log file locations
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  /home/user/public/test-site.com/log/error.log
CustomLog /home/user/public/test-site.com/log/access.log combined
```

(first line changed)

Comment: SSL mod is enabled... i've changed the port and restarted the server. I get the messages... [....] Restarting web server: apache2 `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`. When restarting the server.

Comment: yes, you can remove the "NameVirtualHost *:80" in ports.conf inf you do not want any vhost on port 80, or add a vhost for port 80

Comment: I've removed that line. The warning has gone. But still SSL is still not working. I'll update my question with the description of the certificate.

Comment: is your SSL a multi url certificate? www.trybe-ing.com and trybe-ing.com are two different things. seems to me that trybe-ing.com is working fine! but it gets forwarded to www.trybe-ing.com that is NOT ok.. since your ssl is not made for that url

Comment: eg. try to change `ServerName  www.test-site.com` to `ServerName trybe-ing.com`

Comment: also, if you have some sort of DNS forward remove this.. or buy a ssl with multiple URL, or a second ssl...

Comment: I've renamed my ServerName to trybe-ing.com.. doesnt change anything.